# "Arrays = Pointers" *mind blown*. Many years later: "Actually, they don't" *mind blown again*

Tags: c, arrays

Context:

I programmed in C on and off for about 2 years before discovering that `a[i]` is just syntax sugar for `*(a + i)` and was therefore equivalent to *`(i + a)` and `i[a]`. My reality was turned upside down and many a "AHA!" revelationary moment followed in the following few days of study and reading up *("So THAT's why arrays are always passed by reference!"* etc). Since then I've internalised the pointer/array equivalence and held it close to my heart, so imagine what a rude shock it was when I stumbled upon this thing called "Array decay". Here's the typical example:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Length(int*);

int main () {
  int arr[100];
  printf("Length of array: %d\n",(int)(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])));
  printf("Length of array: %d\n",Length(arr));
  return 0;
}

int Length(int arr[]) {
   return sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
}
```

Result:

```
Length of array: 100
Length of array: 2
```

Question:

So it turns out that C has some recognition of arrays after all! In main where the array was declared, the program is able to correctly report on it's size. Now I'm wondering just how much of array syntax is only syntax sugar for pointer operations (previously I had assumed: All of it). C actually does have arrays, what are their limitations? The example shows that it is possible to get their length as long as you're in the same function, what other cool stuff can you do? How far can you go before this decay thing kicks in?

Comment: Try passing `int arr[10][10]` as an argument to a function ;)

Comment: Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Using_sizeof_with_arrays not answer this?

Comment: Syntax error in title: Surely that should be "Arrays == Pointers"? <wink>

Comment: The C FAQ has a whole section about this stuff - have you read it?

Comment: SO is not a blog site. Please read other questions here to see the preferred style and content.

Comment: BTW, `int* p = NULL; p = p;` vs. `int a[1]; a = a;` is one of many examples that show that arrays and pointers aren't equivalent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two operators in "old" C language that do not trigger array type decay: `sizeof` operator and unary `&` operator. `sizeof` evaluates to the size of the entire array (not to pointer size), while `&` returns a pointer of pointer-to-array type (not of pointer-to-pointer type). C99 added `_Alignof`, as Eric noted in the comments.

One more context is mentioned sometimes as well: initialization of char array with string literal (i.e. string literal does not decay to pointer).

One can also put it that way: in *object contexts* (AKA lvalue contexts) arrays retain their "arrayness", while in *value contexts* (AKA rvalue contexts) they immediately decay to pointers.

**P.S.** As a historical remark: one of the ancestors of C language - B language - did actually implement arrays as physical pointers, meaning that each array in B was actually a pointer pointing to an independently allocated memory block. Originally it was assumed that this implementation will carry over to C as well. However, C had to have `struct` types. And B-style arrays created unnecessary complications with having arrays as members of `struct` objects. They would've made initialization of `struct` objects non-trivial, `struct` object would become non-copyable by raw `memcpy` etc. This was deemed unacceptable in C. So, arrays were redesigned into their current form. C arrays are not pointers, but they still emulate the pointer-like behavior of their grandparents from B language, which often confuses people learning C.

(See here http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html for the full story.)

Comment: @Jim Balter: That's not true. The language explicitly states that string literal is an unnamed object of `char [N]` type with static storage duration (where `N` is the number of characters between the `""` plus 1).

Comment: @Jim Balter: You simply show that the term "string literal" is used to refer to a *lexical element*. However, the term has never been restricted to that usage only. The static array object created in response to that lexical element is also formally referred to as "string literal". 6.5.1/4 clearly states that "A string literal is a primary expression. It is an lvalue with type as detailed in 6.4.5.".

Comment: @Jim Balter: Absolutely not, again. You are trying to impose an arbitrary restriction on the scope of the term "string literal". A restriction that clearly does not exist in the language specification. As I quoted above, 6.5.1/4 states that string literal is an object.

Comment: @Jim Balter: "... but a string literal used to initialize a char array is not such an lvalue ..." - you will have to substantiate this statement by something. At this point it is completely baseless. Quite the opposite, 6.5.1 does not make any exceptions. A string literal is such an lvalue.

Comment: @Jim Balter: Needless to add, the non-decaying contexts I provided in my answer above are a direct quote from 6.3.2.1/3, which lists the same three contexts :)

Comment: If it's needless then don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

The size of an array is "lost" when it is passed to a function.  As you point out, `sizeof`, being a compile-time thing, sees the "real" size.  This can work because `sizeof` is not a function at all, as you can demonstrate by using it without parentheses (e.g. `sizeof arr`, though bizarrely `sizeof some_type` is not legal C).

Comment: That's not bizarre ... sizeof expr is straightforward to parse whereas sizeof type is not, e.g., `sizeof long int`

Comment: `sizeof` isn't necessarily compile-time, too.  VLAs work properly, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that arrays and pointers are "equivalent" means neither that they are identical nor even interchangeable. What it means is that **it's pointer arithmetic and array indexing that are equivalent in C, pointers and arrays are different.**

A reference to an object of type array-of-T which appears in an expression decays into a pointer to its first element; the type of the resultant pointer is pointer-to-T.  That is, whenever an array appears in an expression, the compiler implicitly generates a pointer to the array's first element, just as if the programmer had written `&a[0]`.

`sizeof` or `& operator` are the exceptions to this rule.

Also, I recommend the book [Expert C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298), which uses a whole chapter to explain the difference and confusions about pointers and arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Declaring an array as a local or global variable is where it differs from pointers. `int arr[100];` allocates 400 bytes of space, whereas `int *p` only allocates 4. You can use an `int *p` local variable similarly to an array if you malloc some space for it, like

```
int *p = (int *)malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

You also have to remember to free that memory later, of course. You can also feel free to pass a local variable that was declared as `int arr[100]` to a function whose formal parameter has type `int *`. When it comes to function arguments, arrays and pointers are a little more equivalent.

```
i[a]
```

No, that won't work, if i is an int. But the other three forms are equivalent.

Comment: `i[a]` does work, for `i` an integer and `a` an array or pointer.

Comment: "No, that won't work, if i is an int" -- Of course it will, and the OP told you why. Beyond that, this "answer" has nothing to do with the OP's question ... -1.