# String pointer and array of chars in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, compiler-errors

I just start learning C and found some confusion about the string pointer and string(array of char). Can anyone help me to clear my head a bit?

```
// source code
char name[10] = "Apple";
char *name2 = "Orange";

printf("the address of name: %p\n", name);
printf("the address of the first letter of name: %p\n", &(*name));
printf("first letter of name using pointer way: %c\n", *name);
printf("first letter of name using array way: %c\n", name[0]);
printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
printf("the address of name2: %p\n", name2);
printf("the address of the first letter of name2: %p\n", &(*name2));
printf("first letter of name2 using pointer way: %c\n", *name2);
printf("first letter of name2 using array way: %c\n", name2[0]);

// output
the address of name: 0x7fff1ee0ad50
the address of the first letter of name: 0x7fff1ee0ad50
first letter of name using pointer way: A
first letter of name using array way: A
---------------------------------------------
the address of name2: 0x4007b8
the address of the first letter of name2: 0x4007b8
first letter of name2 using pointer way: O
first letter of name2 using array way: O
```

so I assume that both name and name2 point to the address of their own first letter. then my confusion is(see the code below)

```
//code
char *name3; // initialize a char pointer
name3 = "Apple"; // point to the first letter of "Apple", no compile error

char name4[10]; // reserve 10 space in the memory
name4 = "Apple"; // compile errorrrr!!!!!!!!!!
```

I create a char pointer called name2 and name2 pointer to the first letter of "Apple" which is fine, then I create another array of char and allocate 10 space in the memory. and then try to use name4 which is an address points to the first letter of "Apple". As a result, I got a compile error.

I am so frustrated by this programming language. sometimes they works the same way. but sometimes they doesn't. Can anyone explain the reason and if I really want to create a string or array of chars in separated lines. how I can do that???

Many thanks...

Comment: Have you considered learning Python or Java or C# instead? They're much better languages for a beginner.

Comment: @Patashu Absolutely **terrible** comment. This is at a lower-level than any of those languages provide.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters

Comment: @eded This difference between *arrays* and *pointers* is something that, as an assembly programmer (where they're all just addresses!) his tripped me up in the past too. But I'll let one of the C-language experts answer (who will probably cite the spec for you as well.)

Comment: if because "Apple"(char *) is not the same type as name4(array type) during the assignment, why they can work in the same way to get a specific value?? such as *name3 = name3[0], *name4 = name4[0]

Comment: @Patashu thanks for your comment, I already know python, java and C#.

Comment: @eded It should help to mentally think of arrays as being similar to pointers, but you cannot perform the same operations with them. I'm a little fuzzy on this myself, but an array basically represents the concept of `an array of some  compile-time constant finite number of elements of type x` whereas a pointer represents the concept of `a memory location of a type x`. Notice the difference there, and also notice that **both can be used to refer to one or many of the same things**. Internally in the machine, both are represented in the data with the same thing (a machine word size integer)

Comment: I appreciate and feel so surprise that many friends are trying to help here. Many many thanks guys :)

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Possible duplicate of [Pointer vs array in C, non-trivial difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660752/pointer-vs-array-in-c-non-trivial-difference), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996334/arrays-pointers-mind-blown-many-years-later-actually-they-dont-mind/16996384#16996384 and many others. Read the FAQ: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: @AndreyT Excellent link, thanks. Yes. This topic is complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can initialize an array when you declare it, like this:

```
int n[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
char c[5] = { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', '\0' };
```

But since we typically treat char arrays as strings, C allows a special case:

```
char c[5] = "data";  // Terminating null character is added.
```

However, once you've declared an array, you can't reassign it.  Why?  Consider an assignment like

```
char *my_str = "foo";  // Declare and initialize a char pointer.
my_str = "bar";        // Change its value.
```

The first line declares a char pointer and "aims" it at the first letter in `foo`.  Since `foo` is a string constant, it resides somewhere in memory with all the other constants.  When you reassign the pointer, you're assigning a new value to it: the address of `bar`.  But the original string, `foo` remains unchanged.  You've moved the pointer, but haven't altered the data.

When you declare an array, however, you aren't declaring a pointer at all.  You're reserving a certain amount of memory and giving it a name.  So the line

```
char c[5] = "data";
```

starts with the string constant `data`, then allocates 5 new bytes, calls them `c`, and copies the string into them.  You can *access* the elements of the array exactly as if you'd declared a pointer to them; arrays and pointers are (for most purposes) interchangeable in that way.

*But since arrays are not pointers, you cannot reassign them.*

You can't make `c` "point" anywhere else, because it's not a pointer; it's the name of an area of memory.

You *can* change the value of the string, either one character at a time, or by calling a function like `strcpy()`:

```
c[3] = 'e';       // Now c = "date", or 'd', 'a', 't', 'e', '\0'
strcpy(c, "hi");  // Now c = 'h', 'i', '\0', 'e', '\0'
strcpy(c, "too long!") // Error: overflows into memory we don't own.
```

---

**Efficiency Tip**

Note, also, that initializing an array generally makes a copy of the data: the original string is copied from the constant area to the data area, where your program can change it.  Of course, this means you're using twice as much memory as you may have expected.  You can avoid the copy and generally save memory by declaring a pointer instead.  That leaves the string in the constant area and allocates only enough memory for a pointer, regardless of the length of the string.

Comment: yes, I assume that it makes a copy of string instead pointing to a string constant and that is the reason why we use strcpy there

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly reassign a value to an array type (e.g. your array of ten `char`s `name4`). To the compiler, `name4` is an "array" and you cannot use the assignment `=` operator to write to an array with a string literal.

In order to actually move the content of the string "Apple" into the ten byte array you allocated for it (`name4`), you must use `strcpy()` or something of that sort.

What you are doing with `name3` is pretty different. It is created as a `char *` and initialized to garbage, or zero (you don't know for sure at this point). Then, you assign into it the *location* of the static string "Apple". This is a string that lives in read-only memory, and attempting to write to the memory that the `name3` pointer points to can never succeed.

Based on this, you can surmise that the last statement attempts to assign the memory location of a static string to something somewhere else that represents a collection of 10 `char`s. The language does not provide you with a pre-determined way to perform this task.

Herein lies its power.

Comment: thanks for you reply, as you said if I can not assign a value to an array type, then why I can do -> char name[10] = "Apple"; ??

Comment: You may initialize an array to a string in that way, but not use it for assignment afterwards. That is a very good question and easy to get confused with. Essentially, the `=` operator is not actually the same thing the first time you use it on a variable as compared to the second time you use it on a variable. This is obviously bewildering to the beginner, but the answer involves an understanding of assembly language

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
char *name3 = "Apple";
```

you are declaring `name3` to point to the static string `"Apple"`.  If you're familiar with higher-level languages, you can think of this as immutable (I'm going to explain it in this context because it sounds like you've programmed before; for the technical rationale, check the C standard).

When you say

```
char name4[10];
name4 = "Apple";
```

you get an error because you first declare an array of 10 chars (in other words, you are 'pointing' to the start of a 10-byte section of *mutable* memory), and then attempt to assign the *immutable* value `"Apple"` to this array.  In the latter case, the actual data allocation occurs in some read-only segment of memory.

This means that the types do not match:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[10]' from type 'char *'
```

If you want `name4` to have the value `"Apple"`, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(name4, "Apple");
```

---

If you want `name4` to have the initial value `"Apple"`, you can do that as well:

```
char name4[10] = "Apple"; // shorthand for {'A', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', '\0'}
```

The reason that this works, whereas your previous example does not, is because `"Apple"` is a valid array initialiser for a `char[]`.  In other words, you are creating a 10-byte char array, and setting its initial value to `"Apple"` (with 0s in the remaining places).

This might make more sense if you think of an int array:

```
int array[3] = {1, 2, 3}; // initialise array
```

---

Probably the easiest colloquial explanation I can think of is that an array is a collection of buckets for things, whereas the static string `"Apple"` is a single thing 'over there'.

`strcpy(name4, "Apple")` works because it copies each of the things (characters) in `"Apple"` into `name4` one by one.

However, it doesn't make sense to say, 'this collection of buckets is equal to that thing over there'.  It only makes sense to 'fill' the buckets with values.

Comment: thanks, I understand at beginning, then I got kinda confused. why I can not assign immutable value to this array since char name4[10] = "Apple" works, and why use strcpy instead to make it works? any further explanation will be really helpful

Comment: @eded - I added some additional clarification.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Although pointer and array seems familiar, they are different. the `char *name3` is just a pointer to `char`, it takes no more memory than a pointer. it just store a address in it, so you can assign a string to it then the address stored in `name3` change to the address of `"Apple"`.

But your `name4` is an array of `char[10]`, it holds the memory of 10 chars, if you want to assign it, you need to use `strcpy` or something to write it's memory, but not assign it with an address like `"Apple"`.

Comment: This difference between array-of-char and pointer-to-char is what I was hoping to see.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help clear it up also:

```
int main() {
    char* ptr   = "Hello";
    char  arr[] = "Goodbye";

    // These both work, as expected:
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    printf("%s\n", &arr);   // also works!

    printf("ptr  = %p\n", ptr);
    printf("&ptr = %p\n", &ptr);
    printf("arr  = %p\n", arr);
    printf("&arr = %p\n", &arr);

    return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
Hello
Goodbye
Goodbye
ptr  = 0021578C         
&ptr = 0042FE2C         
arr  = 0042FE1C         \__ Same!
&arr = 0042FE1C         /
```

So we see that `arr == &arr`.  Since it's an array, the compiler knows that you are always going to want the address of the first byte, regardless of how it's used.

`arr` is an array of 7+1 bytes, that are on the *stack* of `main()`. The compiler generates instructions tho reserve those bytes, and then populate it with "Goodbye".  There is no pointer!

`ptr` on the other hand, is a pointer, a 4-byte integer, also on the stack.  That's why `&ptr` is very close to `&arr`.  But what it *points* to, is a static string ("Hello"), that is off in the read-only section of the executable (which is why `ptr`'s value is a very different number).

Comment: You are relying on undefined behavior.  `printf("%s\n", &arr)` happens to work for you, but it is not guaranteed to work by the standard.  `&arr` is of type `char(*)[8]`, that is: "pointer to an array of 8 chars".  There is no guarantee that it will correctly convert to a `char*` the way you expect.

Comment: True, and yech.  The name of an array evaluates to the address of its first element.  That's why `*(arr+1)` works.  Using the extra `&` before the name is redundant, non-standard, and confusing.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks guys - good point. Visual Studio didn't complain, but I didn't try it in `gcc -Wall`. I think my mistakes, and your comments are very helpful together, in understanding this, so I'm going to leave it be.